# List of objects to table

Tags: angular

I have a list of objects and the object structure is the same for all the objects in the list. I am trying to generate a table. My frontend is angular.
Here is my data (component.ts)

```js
data =[
    {name: "apple", type: "fruit"},
    {name: "peach", type: "fruit"},
    {name: "banan", type: "fruit"},
    {name: "onion", type: "vegetable"},
    {name: "carrot", type: "vegetable"}
]
table_headers = Object.keys(data[0]) //gives me an array ["name", "type"]
```

My code for rendering this (component.html)

```html
<table>
     <tr *ngFor="let header in table_headers">
         <th>{{header}}</th>
     <tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let item in data | keyvalue">
         <td>{{item.key}}</td>
         <td>{{item.value}}</td>
     <tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to find if Angular or any other framework supports rendering table without doing all this. Something like a simple function where I can pass the list of obj and render a table.

Comment: Hi, you can wrap your code into a tableComponent that recives data and prints a table.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks like Angular/React facilitates creation of such UI components. For example table structure that you created would have been difficult with plain JS and HTML. They don't provide readymade UI library as a part of framework. For such needs you need to rely on 3rd party UI libraries like ngPrime or KendoUI or angular-material which are available as npm packages. In your case if you want to render data in tabular format only this would be the best way and you can wrap your logic inside a angular component with data as input, this way you can reuse it at other places. In case your plan is to have advanced features like pagination, sorting, filtering,  grouping, you might want to check out packages like ngGrid(though are are many and can be found on npm.org)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the pipe "keyvalue" when you dont need to.

Your code should look like this:

```
<table>
     <tr *ngFor="let header in table_headers">
         <th>{{header}}</th>
     <tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let item in data">
         <td>{{item.name}}</td>
         <td>{{item.type}}</td>
     <tr>
</table>
```

keyvalue pipe is to access the key name not its value